# How to add multiple static geo points with different marker Icons in flutter_osm_plugin

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap

In my Flutter application, I am using the Osm Flutter plugin and I need to show the list of geo-locations with different icons. One with a user icon and the other with different icons. I am not sure which property solves the problem.